# Reading and writing to the same file

Tags: perl

I'm using this code I found online to read a properties file in my Perl script:

```
open (CONFIG, "myfile.properties");
while (CONFIG){
  chomp;     #no new line
  s/#.*//;   #no comments
  s/^\s+//;  #no leading white space
  s/\s+$//;  #no trailing white space
  next unless length;
  my ($var, $value) = split (/\s* = \s*/, $_, 2);
  $$var = $value;
}
```

Is it posssible to also write to the text file inside this while loop? Let's say the text file looks like this:

```
#Some comments
a_variale = 5
a_path    = /home/user/path

write_to_this_variable = ""
```

How can I put some text in `write_to_this_variable`?

Comment: Try MODE argument - http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html.

Comment: why don't you try using a module to do the reading and writing for you. E.g. see [Config::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/Config::Tiny) or [Config::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/Config::Simple).

Comment: You should use the three-argument-version of `open` together with lexical filehandles and error checking. So for example `open my $config_fh, '<', 'myfile.properties' or die $!;`

Answer (score 1):

It is not really practical to overwrite text files where you have variable length records (lines).  It is normal to copy the file, something like this:

```
my $filename = 'myfile.properites';
open(my $in, '<', $filename) or die "Unable to open '$filename' for read: $!";

my $newfile = "$filename.new";
open(my $out, '>', $newfile) or die "Unable to open '$newfile' for write: $!";

while (<$in>) {
    s/(write_to_this_variable =) ""/$1 "some text"/;
    print $out;
}

close $in;
close $out;

rename $newfile,$filename or die "unable to rename '$newfile' to '$filename': $!";
```

You might have to sanitse the text you are writing with something like `\Q` if it contains non-alphanumerics.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a program that uses the [`Config::Std`](https://metacpan.org/module/Config%3a%3aStd) module to read an write a simple config file like yours. As far as I know it is the only module that will preserve any comments in the original file.

There are two points to note:

1. The first hash key in `$props{''}{write_to_this_variable}` forms the name of the config file section that will contain the value. If there are no sections, as for your file, then you must use an empty string here
2. If you need quotes around the a value then you must add these explicitly when you are assigning to the hash element, as I do here with `'"Some text"'`

I think the rest of the program is self-explanatory.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Config::Std { def_sep => ' = ' };

my %props;
read_config 'myfile.properties', %props;

$props{''}{write_to_this_variable} = '"Some text"';

write_config %props;
```

**output**

```
#Some comments
a_variale = 5
a_path = /home/user/path

write_to_this_variable = "Some text"
```